# Python: Find max value along one axis in 3d matrix, make non-max values zero

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3-d matrix as shown below and would like to take the max value along axis 1, and keep all non-max values to zero.

```
A = np.random.rand(3,3,2)

  [[[0.34444547, 0.50260393],
    [0.93374423, 0.39021899],
    [0.94485653, 0.9264881 ]],

   [[0.95446736, 0.335068  ],
    [0.35971558, 0.11732342],
    [0.72065402, 0.36436023]],

   [[0.56911013, 0.04456443],
    [0.17239996, 0.96278067],
    [0.26004909, 0.06767436]]]
```

Desired result:

```
   [[0         , 0         ],
    [0         , 0         ],
    [0.94485653, 0.9264881]],

   [[0.95446736, 0          ],
    [0         , 0          ],
    [0         , 0.36436023]],

   [[0.56911013, 0         ],
    [0         , 0.96278067],
    [0         , 0         ]]])
```

I have tried:

```
B = np.zeros_like(A)  #return matrix of zero with same shape as A

max_idx = np.argmax(A, axis=1) #index along axis 1 with max value

    array([[2, 0],
           [2, 2],
           [0, 2],
           [0, 1]])

C = np.max(A, axis=1, keepdims = True) #gives a (4,1,2) matrix of max value along axis 1

    array([[[0.95377958, 0.92940525]],
           [[0.94485653, 0.9264881 ]],
           [[0.95446736, 0.36436023]],
           [[0.56911013, 0.96278067]]])
```

But I can't figure out how to combine these ideas together to get my desired output. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [3 dimensional index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) of your max values from `max_idx`. The values in `max_idx` are the index along axis 1 of your max values. There are six values since your other axes are 3 and 2 (3 x 2 = 6). You just have to realize the order that numpy goes through them to get the index for each of the other axes. You iterate over the last axes first:

```
d0, d1, d2 = A.shape
a0 = [i for i in range(d0) for _ in range(d2)]   # [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
a1 = max_idx.flatten()                           # [2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]
a2 = [k for _ in range(d0) for k in range(d2)]   # [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

B[a0, a1, a2] = A[a0, a1, a2]
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.94485653, 0.9264881 ]],

       [[0.95446736, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.36436023]],

       [[0.56911013, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.96278067],
        [0.        , 0.        ]]])
```

Comment: Glad to hear! If this was helpful for you please consider [upvoting and/or accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.